# Pandas - how to select rows which contain specific value in it

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to select all rows which contains "--->", but getting just some of them. I would like to see whole row if it is contains "--->" in any "cell".

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['1--->3','4','6',''],'B':['2','4','--->8','4'],'C'['5','0','4','2--->']})
print df
print "------------------------------"

st = df[df[df.columns.any()].str.contains("--->", na=False)]

print st

print "------------------------------"

rm = df.loc[df[df.columns.all(0)].str.contains("--->", na=False)]
print rm

rev = df[~df[df.columns.all()].str.contains('^((?!--->).)*$', 
regex=True,na=False)]

print rev

        A      B      C
0  1--->3      2      5
1       4      4      0
2       6  --->8      4
3              4  2--->
------------------------------
```

st output

```
        A  B  C
0  1--->3  2  5
------------------------------
```

rm output

```
  A  B      C
3    4  2--->
```

rev output 
    A  B      C
    3    4  2--->

I am expecting to see

```
        A      B      C
0  1--->3      2      5
2       6  --->8      4
3              4  2--->
```

Comment: oh wow, is this python2? Hey guys, we got a live one * *snigger* *. No, jk. But please update to python3.

Comment: I know, I know. but it is required to use python 2 for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) the dataframe, so that you can use `str` accessor on stacked values. This gives you boolean for each cell value of the dataframe. `unstack` it and then [`.any(1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) seturn whether any element is True, over a row.

```
df[df.stack().str.contains('--->').unstack().any(1)]
```

Output:

```
        A   B       C
0   1--->3  2       5
2   6       --->8   4
3           4       2--->
```

Comment: harvpan - thank you!!! works perfectly for me! I need a keep exploring pandas module.

Comment: @harvpan Can you please explain the solution?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1--->3', '4', '6', ''], 'B': ['2', '4', '--->8', '4'], 'C': ['5', '0', '4', '2--->']})
print(df)
print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
filtered_df = df[(df['A'].str.contains('--->')) | (df['B'].str.contains('--->')) | (df['C'].str.contains('--->'))]
print(filtered_df)
```

output

```
        A      B      C
0  1--->3      2      5
1       4      4      0
2       6  --->8      4
3              4  2--->
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        A      B      C
0  1--->3      2      5
2       6  --->8      4
3              4  2--->
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to do so is to simply apply a function with a lambda

```
def only_arrow(row):    
    for r in row:
        if "-->" in r:
            return True
    return False
```

and apply it on your df (this will give you true/false values as series):

```
result = df.apply(lambda x : only_arrow(x), axis=1)

0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
```

remove the indexes where it 'False'

```
df.drop(result[result==False].index, inplace=True)
```

result:

[image]